# Select records using crystal report with null condition

Tags: crystal-reports

I was trying to filter the data in database with the following formula in my crystal report and one of the condition is to included the data even this, '{vw_CandidateProfile.Type}' is null or empty string. But the formula below doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
{vw_CandidateProfile.Candidate_Code} = '881225095228' 
AND (
        {vw_CandidateProfile.Type} IN ['NGO','EDU','PRS','PPR','PPS','TTL','OTH'] 
        OR ISNULL({vw_CandidateProfile.Type})
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution in which the IsNull() field has to comes before the field which is no IsNull().

```
{vw_CandidateProfile.Type} IN ['NGO','EDU','PRS','PPR','PPS','TTL','OTH'] 
    OR ISNULL({vw_CandidateProfile.Type})
```

**becomes**

```
ISNULL({vw_CandidateProfile.Type})
    OR {vw_CandidateProfile.Type} IN ['NGO','EDU','PRS','PPR','PPS','TTL','OTH']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use formula: in Select Expert

```
ToText({vw_CandidateProfile.Type}) = ""
```